# How to grep for a word alone from a file if few search characters are known

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep, sh

How can I fetch only word from a file if I have few search characters known?

My file contents:

```
This is a sample file 
to fetch particular word
if I have a search characters known.
```

For instance if my search pattern is "**SAM**" , output expected is ***sample***

In grep -w option, I will have to specify entire word and entire line that has the word is obtained.

Comment: `grep -oP 'sam\w*' file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try:

```
grep -o '\w*sam\w*' file
```

or

```
grep -o '\S*sam\S*' file
```

depends on what you want.

Comment: Aren't they looking for a word? This will include pretty much every character except spaces e.g `sam*&^%%&^%$^$ӝõ࠹4`

Comment: @123 way to break the comments!

Comment: @123 how did you make the `࠹4 –` after your name? :-)

Comment: @Kent No idea, was just typing unicode characters. Only seems to work with numbers though. Could look in the source i suppose.

Comment: @123 I've checked source, your unicode chars are in `<code>` block, including the `4[]`

Comment: The `\S*` will include non-word constituent characters as @123 mentions (e.g. `known.` with a trailing period) while the `\w*` will include underscores which may or may not be desirable depending on the OPs real input and definition of a "word".

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with awk too:

```
awk -v RS='[^[:alpha:]]' '/sam/'
```

With `RS` I set the separator to any non-alphanumeric characters (acording with the Ed Morton's tip of the comments), then each loop will contain a word. Finally we filter the pattern that we want in the regex, and... voilà

Comment: Thanks, @TomFenech. Now I've added a little explanation. :)

Comment: That would incorrectly output `known.` (note the trailing period) when searching for `known`. For this approach to work you'd have to set RS as something like `RS="[^[:alpha:]]"` (depending on the OPs definition of a "word") but then it's gawk-dependent.

Comment: Good point, @EdMorton! Literally :) I've edited the answer. Thank you very much, I didn't realize.